# Temporarily switch off display without moving windows with dwm

Tags: multi-monitor, xrandr, dwm

I have a dual monitor setup. Certain screensharing apps (slack in this case) do not let me choose which screen to display, and instead show absolutely everything when I share my screen (which is bad, because the window is too small). If I turn the external monitor off with xrandr, then my window manager collapses all my workspaces from one window into the other, which is inconvenient because it messes up my window placement (and I have to set it back up after the call).

What I'd like to have is a way to *temporarily* switch the monitor off, so that it doesn't get shared by these applications, but I can turn it back on afterwards to get my desktop back in the situation it was previously.

Just in case, my window manager is dwm (but I don't think that's relevant).

Comment: It's your window manager that decides to move the windows, so it's definitely relevant. For all I know (I don't know dwm), that behavior is baked in and the only solution would be to use a different window manager.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' That makes sense. I suppose there are two sides to the interaction - X sends a signal to the WM indicating the display has been deactivated, and the WM interprets that signal and decides to move windows. Changing the WM would change the response to the "deactivate display" event in all cases, which is actually not what I want (I like that the workspaces collapse when I want to actually disconnect the monitor). I am hoping (maybe in vain) that there is an X event like "suspend display" which does not trigger the same signal as deactivation.